# Why isn't this byte-to-string function invertible (and how can I make it be?)

Tags: java, character-encoding, cryptography

I'm writing some stuff with Java's cryptography system, which wants to do everything as `byte[]`. Unfortunately, I need to pass things over a messaging layer elsewhere, that wants to use `String`. I tried to make back-and-forth translation functions with:

```
    public static String bytesToString(byte[] input){
        return new String(input, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
    public static byte[] stringToBytes(String input){
        return input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
```

But those don't actually invert each other: I have a test program that breaks if I include:

```
signature = stringToBytes(bytesToString(signature));
```

(i.e., if I take the `byte[]` signature, change it to a string and change it back, it somehow doesn't come out the same.) I'm certain this is the problem, as commenting out that one line makes everything work fine.

Is there a different character encoding that would make this work, or..? I'm also curious why this implementation isn't working. Are there some chars that multiple bytes map to, or what?

Comment: Is `signature` a correctly encoded value? How did you generate it?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis signature comes from `Signature.sign()` (from `java.security`). I'm not necessarily certain what you mean by "correctly encoded", but it correctly recognizes signed keys if I never try to translate it to a string, so I'm confident that the byte array is getting changed.

Comment: Not all byte sequences are valid UTF8 character sequences. ISO_8859_1 is lossless, but you will get non-printable characters. You should use Base64 to encode bytes into a printable string, and vice versa.

Comment: The `byte[]` returned by `sign()` doesn't seem to represent textual data.

Comment: @JBNizet Okay. So, just to make sure I understand what was happening, `new String(someBadSetOfBytes)` will just quietly drop thing it encounters that it doesn't like? (Or map them onto some default character?)

Comment: @EdwardPeters From the JavaDoc: "The behavior of this constructor when the given bytes are not valid in the default charset is **unspecified**." So in principle it *could* also throw a (runtime) exception. Afaik the Oracle implementation indeed just drops anything it doesn't like.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Oh my. I think I'm just gonna go ahead and add that constructor to my "Never Use" pile...